# The "floatingtext" property for MaterialFx is not working properly for me - When rendered the floating text property remains hidden

Tags: fxml, materialfx

For example i am using this in my fxml file:

```
<MFXTextField fx:id="username" floatMode="BORDER" floatingText="username" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" prefHeight="24.0" prefWidth="361.0">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </MFXTextField>
```

This renders just fine in scenebuilder, but the same loads weirdly when i run the same fxml in intellij

[This is how it loads via Intellij. Notice the float text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfxj3.png)

Same fxml previewed in scenebuilder:
[scenebuilder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xt6Y.png)

same rendering as i get with scenebuilder preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it figured out. Was missing to set the transparent background -

```
 MFXThemeManager.addOn(scene, Themes.DEFAULT, Themes.LEGACY);
    scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```